# How do I synchronize a UV Map re-packed with the uv-packer add-on with an existing texture map?

Tags: uv, texture-baking

I'm customizing VR Chat avatars with Blender (currently 2.9, looking to upgrade to 3.x). This implies they will end up in Unity on their way to VR Chat. I understand how to combines meshes to single mesh, and how to use the Material Combiner add-on to create a single file texture atlas with an associated UV map. I understand that the uv-packer add-on (and evidently newer post 3.6 versions of Blender) can do a much better job of rejiggering the UV map to fit in a smaller space. The thing that I don't understand is how to end up with the same changes to the texture atlas, i.e. every time a UV is moved to a new place in the new map, I want the associated part of the texture map to also be changed so that the model looks identical. Naturally I want this to happen automagically so I don't have to make any changes by hand.

So how do I use a UV re-packer to optimize my UV map while simultaneously re-arranging the texture atlas to follow the newly optimized UV map? I have the feeling I'm missing something obvious here. I understand the general relationship between the 2d texture atlas and the way the UV map explains how to wrap that around the model, but I haven't done a lot of unwrapping or manual UV mapping myself.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The general answer is, you don't.  You only atlas once your textures (which includes the original UV used to access them) are finalized.  But a pro company would probably have scripts running overnight that built texture atlases, and then, you only ever use, in-game, what was built yesterday.  You *could* change the atlas UV (not some original UV), but live repacking is totally out of the question.